# Mongoose removes callback functions for "Item.insertMany()" and "Item.find()" methods. Can I use these methods in place of the removed methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I'm practicing building a todo list app and after discovering that callback functions can no longer be used for `Items.insertMany()` and `Item.find()` methods, I discovered an alternative. However, I want to know what might be wrong with this code when I have to insert **records** and **display** them also on the page.

In other words, I want to insert records into the database, then find them and display them on the page.

```js
const defaultItems = [study, practice, eat];

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  Item.find().then(function(){

  if (defaultItems.length === 0){
    Item.insertMany(defaultItems).then(function(){
        console.log("Added successfully!");
      }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
      });
      res.redirect("/");
    } else {
      res.render("list", {listTitle: "Today", newListItems: defaultItems});
    }
  }).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
  })
});
```

What could be wrong with this code? I have not seen an error yet but I just used imagination to make it up following the alternatives I read, about the mentioned method calls.

**Below is the code from the ejs file**

```html
<div class="box" id="heading">
  <h1> <%= listTitle %> </h1>
</div>

<div class="box">

<% newListItems.forEach(function(item){ %>
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <p> <%= item.name %> </p>
  </div>
<% }); %>

  <form class="item" action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="New Item" autocomplete="off">
    <button type="submit" name="list">+</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The `if (defaultItems.length === 0)` doesn't make sense. You check if the array is empty to insert no element in the collection.  Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You are inserting to the db on the condition that `defaultItems` is empty. Meaning that nothing will ever get inserted.

Comment: @Ipizzinidev  @Innovin

I have edited the original post to add the array in question, content of which are collections that had been created using the **Item** model.

However, aside the issue of the array you pointed out, is the way I structured the code okay? I mean, especially with the way I wrote and/or nested the `then ()` and `catch ()` error handling functions.